# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) - Not working on Python 3.8

Tags: python, json, list, python-requests, python-responses

Hey I've just started to use Python 3.8 and I get bug for the last line. It works perfectly on python 3.6 how cam I make it work on Python 3.6?

in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import requests
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
user = "travel.like.this"
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + user
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
response = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
jsonObject = response.select("body > script:nth-of-type(1)")[0].text.replace('window._sharedData =','').replace(';','')
data = json.loads(jsonObject)
```

Comment: what is the value of `jsonObject`? Because it looks like it is not valid JSON.

Comment: It should be a string of the html request. I checked further, it seems that one line works on python 3.6 while on python 3.8 it returns nothing:

jsonObject = response.select("body > script:nth-of-type(1)")[0].text.replace('window._sharedData =','').replace(';','')

Answer (score 0):

maybe in `python 3.8`, the `requests` lib is `not handling the empty response` and its coded to raise an error when its empty.

this error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

is because the json response is `empty`, its a `void` string. ----> `b''`

(i didnt see the json, but i assume its empty and thats why its raising error)

from my experience:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://my_static_website.com/")
print(response.status_code) # 200
print(response.json())
```

out

```
200

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```